# Is there a way to assign tasks and appointments to Office 365 Groups through Dynamics CRM?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, office365

With the ability to create office 365 groups for records in CRM, is there a way to assign tasks and appointments to the group? I'm hoping to be able to show items assigned to a group in the user's outlook calendar.

Is there a simple way to do this? If not, can somebody point me in the right direction to do this a more advanced way?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it isn't available but a future link up between O365 planner and dynamics crm is on the cards.
http://windowsitpro.com/office-365/office-365-planner